# How to assign image url dynamically using $.map in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How to assign image tag attributes data dynamically using `$.map` loop below is my html and jquery code.

html:-

```
<div class="justify-content-center">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class='chart-icon'>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </i>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="justify-content-center">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class='chart-icon'>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </i>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="justify-content-center">
  <div class="icons">
    <i class='chart-icon'>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </i>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

jquery code:-

```
($.map(algoimg, function (item) {

    $(".justify-content-center").find("img").attr("src", item.ImageURL).attr("alt", item.StrategyName);
    $(".justify-content-center").find("span").html(item.StrategyName);       

}));
```

In the above jQuery logic is working fine and the `item.ImageURL` will give the unique image url to each `justify-content-center` class div img but the problem is each `justify-content-center` class img url is taking the last image url to each `justify-content-center` class. Can you please suggest me where I did the mistake here

Sorry for my bad English and if any code required I will share.

Comment: Off topic: Use `map` to map values and [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop.

Comment: `$(".justify-content-center")` selects all of them, `.find("img")` find all images (ie all 3), `.attr` returns the attribute of the first one - so will always be the first one.  It's hard to see how you can think this would loop through each `-content-center`.   `map` *might* be useful here, but it's hard to tell without know what algoimg is.

Comment: It *looks like* you could just change to `($.map(algoimg, function (item, idx) { $(".justify-content-center").eq(idx).find("img")...`

Comment: Agree with other commenters here, but also you haven't shown us what data the `algoimg` variable contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iteration of your loop is targeting every single `.justify-content-center` element on your page. To address this, you want to only target the element at the current index of your loop.

```
$.map(algoimg, function (item, index) {
    $('.justify-content-center').eq(index).find("img").attr("src", item.ImageURL).attr("alt", item.StrategyName);
    $('.justify-content-center').eq(index).find("span").html(item.StrategyName);  
}
```

In general there are other better ways to do this overall, but this will fix your current issue

Comment: It is not for performance, your initial example is literally targeting every one of those divs on every single loop. To target one at a time, you need to store it first and specifically reference each individual one in sequence

Comment: It's not my example.

Comment: I saw your name above, my mistake. It's not a red herring, it's trying to encourage a clearly junior javascript developer into good habits. This is how I would solve the problem above

Comment: The proper way would be to do it the other way around since algoimg is already defined, using $('.justify-content-center').each, but didn't want to confuse things too much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253339/discussion-between-jmcgriz-and-freedomn-m).